# Same magnitude on different axes?

Tags: variables, vector, unity-game-engine, magnitude

Is it possible to take the magnitude of an object on one axis and put it inside of a variable and give it to a separate object on a different axis? Does magnitude not work that way?

Answer (score -1):

```
//this is the first axis    
Vector3 axis1 = whatever;
//this is the second axis
Vector3 axis2 = whatever;
//this normalizes the second axis
axis2.Normalize();
//this multiplies the the second axis with the first axis' magnitude
axis2 *= axis1.magnitude;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helps, but I think I don't understand if "whatever" is supposed to be a variable...?

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just posting code.

Comment: Thanks Tony! I could really use further explanation. Someone suggested what I'm really asking for is a way to take the position of something on one axis and pass it to a different object on a separate axis.

Comment: And won't this throw an error at me for implicitly converting type?

Comment: -1 for not explaining, ok sorry i figured that it was simple enough you could figure it out; edited the answer

if you really had to effort to thumb down and post a comment, why couldn't you answer Tony?

Comment: How do i post sample code without answering my question?

Comment: Sorry what are you asking?